# Visual Studio Code Keyboard Shortcut for Dart Plugin Not Working

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

Using the Dart Code plugin to Visual Studio Code on Windows and trying to make the `Escape` key take my cursor from the "PROBLEMS" tab into the active editor doesn't appear to work like I thought it would.

I have edited `keybindings.json` successfully for other tabs in the list, but for some reason the "PROBLEMS" (Dart's auto syntax checker) tab doesn't work.

Below are two examples, the first one works, and the second does not.

The first is for when I've got the "TERMINAL" tab open and pressing `escape` takes my cursor back to the active editor. This works just fine.

The second is supposed to do the same thing for the "PROBLEMS" tab, but does not function.

```
  {
    "key": "escape",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
    "when": "workbench.panel.markers"
  },
  {
    "key": "escape",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
```

I've tried the `workbench.panel.markers | terminalFocus` behavior for the `when` clause, but it didn't work either.

This should be pretty simple, but I can't see what I'm missing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shift the focus from the "Problems" tab to the active editor the following keyboard shortcut works with VSCODE version 1.86.2 (on linux):

```json
{
   "key": "escape",
   "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
   "when": "focusedView == workbench.panel.markers.view"
}
```

Comment: Dan R, you are a lifesaver. Can you tell me how you figured this out? I want to be able to do this myself. :-)

Comment: Sure, In VSCode I selected `Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`. In the top search field I entered "problem" and had a look at the `When` column. The condition `"focusedView == workbench.panel.markers.view"` looked similar to your guess so I tried that. Btw, the single quotes around `workbench.panel.markers.view` appeared when copying from VsCode and pasting to the `keybindings.json` file. It works without them and I will amend my answer.